# Unable to store and retrieve user.uid from firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

Initially I was unable to store and  retrieve the uid of a user in firebase using the below given code. Empty string was getting stored into firebas

Initial code:

```
final userProvider = StateProvider<ChatUserModel?>((ref) => null);
```

....

```
void createCommunity(String name, BuildContext context) async {
state = true;
final uid = _ref.read(userProvider)?.uid ?? '';
Community community = Community(
  id: name,
  name: name,
  banner: bannerDefault,
  avatar: avatarDefault,
  members: [uid],
  mods: [uid],
);
```

....

```
final res = await _communityRepository.createCommunity(community);
state = false;
res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
  showSnackBar(context, 'Community created successfully');
  Routemaster.of(context).pop();
});

Stream<List<Community>> getUserCommunities() {
    final uid = _ref.read(userProvider)!.uid;
    return _communityRepository.getUserCommunities(uid);
  }
```

....

```
Stream<List<Community>> getUserCommunities(String uid) {
return _communities
    .where('members', arrayContains: uid)
    .snapshots()
    .map((event) {
  List<Community> communities = [];
  for (var doc in event.docs) {
    communities.add(Community.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }
  return communities;
});
}
```

I tried to modify it myself to store the uid in firebase. Now it is getting stored instead of empty string getting stored

Modified code:

```
void createCommunity(String name, BuildContext context) async {
state = true;
final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user != null) {
  DocumentSnapshot userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get();

  final uid = user.uid;
  Community community = Community(
    id: name,
    name: name,
    banner: bannerDefault,
    avatar: avatarDefault,
    members: [uid],
    mods: [uid],
  );
```

So now that the uid is getting stored into firebase correctly, when I tried to apply the same solution to getUserCommunities() function, it is giving me return type errors and various other errors. Any suggestions to retrieve the user id correctly?

Links for reference:

1. userProvider - https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/ff882518b75279f75dd9eaf39bbff7490a042324/lib/auth/auth_controller.dart#L4
2. createCommunity - https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/ff882518b75279f75dd9eaf39bbff7490a042324/lib/widgets/community-chat/controller/community_controller.dart
3. getUserCommunities() - https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/ff882518b75279f75dd9eaf39bbff7490a042324/lib/widgets/community-chat/repository/community_repository.dart